# Mixing two different primers?

Tags: walls, painting

Can I cut in my walls with a latex primer sealer by gliden if I already rolled walls with zinser oil base sealer

Comment: While not best practice you can prime with latex over the oil prime.  Do not do it the other way around however.

Comment: @James - Your comment reads like an answer. Consider moving it to the answer box.

Comment: What type of paint are you using on the walls? The type of primer should match the type of paint being applied.

Answer (score 1):

While not best practice you can prime with latex over the oil prime.

For future reference though, do not do it the other way around...it ends poorly.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with zinser oil (which I use and is great for bathrooms) then I would actually suggest using a latex primer if you will end with a latex paint.  I have had issues with latex paint being applied to oil based primers so I would at least do a quick coat with latex primer.

If you are going oil paint at the end then no you cannot do this.